# How can i show some loading screen or splash screen while flutter application loads up

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, flutter-layout

I have been working on an app recently. I want to check if the user is logged in and is verified when my app loads up. So I created a Wrapper class to check if the user is logged in and is verified. Then accordingly I would show them either login screen or home screen.

I have assigned home : Wrapper(), in Main.dart .

After that I have wrapper class as

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    // checking if there is user and the user is verified
    bool _isAuth() { 
      if (user != null && user.isVerified) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    return _isAuth() ? MainScreen() : Authenticate();
  }
}
```

**This works fine but the problem is it first flashes the login page and then takes me to the homepage if the user is logged in and is verified but it just works fine if the user is not logged in [see gif image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYvHF.gif)**

Comment: do you use bloc?

Comment: Actually no. I have no knowledge about it.. I think i have to have a look at it.

Comment: yeah in big project it is very helpful  and it is recommended by google if you want to learn it use bloc package ( is little bit less complicated & its code is understandable) and for learn the bloc package use this site https://bloclibrary.dev/#/ you can do what you mentioned above ,with no errors and very easy with bloc

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just have one query. Can i use this now on my project or  I completely need to change the structure of the project?

Comment: it (bloc) take time to understand it needs its own changes & properties(which needs 30 or 40 line of code Usually for each sections) but when you  did that you would be Familiar with that and from that moment on it is easy for you and  it is easy to put it in app only 1 or 2 line of code to use it in app

Comment: by the way could you shar where you wrote `home:` i want to see that and answer your question you can handle but  try learn bloc(my opinion)

Comment: I have home in main.dart file. 
home : Wrapper()
In Wrapper  I am willing to check the authentication of the user.

Answer (score 0):

It probably shows the login page because of the way your logic is being handled. you should do this in `initState` instead of the build method. There are two ways to do this you can either use your wrapper as redirection class or use the build method like you're already doing to toggle the view.

First Method (uses redirection)

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);
    var _isAuth = user != null && user.isVerified;
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => _isAuth ? MainScreen() : Authenticate()),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```

Second Method (uses build method):

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  bool _isAuth = false;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);
    setState(() {
      _isAuth = user != null && user.isVerified;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isLoading
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : _isAuth
            ? MainScreen()
            : Authenticate();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first method and it game me error like ---This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:

Comment: i made a mistake super.initState(); comes first